# Hide soft keyboard after dialog dismiss

Tags: android, keyboard, hide, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I want to hide soft keyboard after AlertDialog dismiss, but it's still visible. Here is my code:

```java
alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

alert.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can find a solution here: http://www.workingfromhere.com/blog/2011/04/27/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard/ OR here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: Both methods are use EditText view, but I haven't it. I haven't EditText. It's dialog in my SettingsActivity. When it's closed keyboard shows :(

Comment: if your keyboard popups on a Dialog, it means your dialog must have a EditText within it. So you can write the above code by passing the window-token of your EditText, & then call dialog.dismiss()

Comment: or if its not the above case.. means if Edittext is not on your dialog, you need to check for which EditText it popsup & hide it before showing the dialog.  If this too doesnt work, plz post your code.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

In **Manifest xml**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

> It will automatically hide soft keyboard on Dismiss of `Dialog`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! It is a bad practice to override properties declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Renjith can you please elaborate why its bad

Comment: it didn't work for me, but edittext hiding (edittext inside dialog) and dialog.dismiss did the job

Comment: @SeshuVinay, I'm just a humble engineer, but if times call me, I becoming Batman :) Take care mate ! :)

Comment: Wow there's 2 hours of my life gone thank you Android :D

Answer (score 17):

I met the same problem. Solved it by doing like this. It doesn't need any reference:

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getDecorView()
                .getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: this is working correct when trying to hide from a DialogFragment

Comment: But it leaves a white shadow temporarily, how to prevent the white shadow?

Comment: what is 'imm' ??

Comment: @BrenddonAnjos `InputMethodManager` object

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem when closing an alert dialog. This seems to do the trick for me.

Inside your DialogFragment

```
public static void closeKB(final View view) 
{
    caller.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }, 1);
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
{
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
            View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null)
    {
        closeKB(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: why using postDelayed?

Answer (score 7):

I use this method:

```
IBinder token = searchTextEntry.getWindowToken();
( ( InputMethodManager ) getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE ) ).hideSoftInputFromWindow( token, 0 );
```

Where `searchTextEntry` is the name of my `EditText` reference.

Comment: I haven't EditText. It's dialog in my SettingsActivity. When it's closed keyboard shows :(

Comment: Worked.  But had to add a number for "hideFlags:".  So "...(token, showFlags: 0, hideFlags:0);"

Answer (score 4):

This works! This will close the keyboard after dialog dismiss

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

Comment: It worked finally after trying too many solutions.Nice thing is it doesn't need any view and check its focus.

Comment: however, you should check for focus existence, otherwise if it is hidden, the keyboard shows up

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void hideKeyboard() {
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    final View view = activity != null ? activity.getCurrentFocus() : null;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (imm != null)
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }, 1);
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    hideKeyboard();
}
```

Comment: why using handler?

Answer (score 0):

All these advices to use `InputMethodManager` are somewhat vague - where exactly to call it,
 and they do not work at least for me.
Yes, keyboard disappears but then the app crashes!?
The main problem is that hiding of keyboard happens at the same time when dialog is disappearing.

To avoid it `dialog.dismiss()` should be called in `view.postDelayed()` after `imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow()` and in my case I set delay as 150.

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone looks for this in kotlin, it would be:

```
private fun hideDeviceKeyboard() {
    val imm = context!!.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0)
}
```