# How to dismiss android keyboard on dialog dismiss?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a dialog box open in my android app, and I have a button when clicked will dismiss the dialog box. The problem is there is also a textedit field, and if its focused and the keyboard is showing, then when I click the cancel button, then dialog goes away, but the keyboard is still showing.

I want to also dismiss the keyboard.

I was searching around, and for threads like this
[Hide soft keyboard after dialog dismiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633792/hide-soft-keyboard-after-dialog-dismiss)

But none of the solutions worked for me. By the way the edittext is a number input type, if that makes a difference somehow.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

```
public void HandleTeamManagement() {
    final Dialog teamDialog = new Dialog(this);
    teamDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    teamDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_team_management);

    final EditText mergeNum = (EditText) teamDialog.findViewById(R.id.group);


    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mergeNum.getWindowToken(), 0);



    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    Button cancelButton = (Button) teamDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            teamDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Dialog
    teamDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the following didn't work for you: `InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);`?

Comment: @omega: Are you frocibly bringing the keyboard up.?

Comment: The keyboard comes up by focusing on the edittext, so no I don't forcibly bring it up.

Comment: I added the code above.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a solution here:

http://www.workingfromhere.com/blog/2011/04/27/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard/

[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Edited: adding code
Try this ..it worked for me

```
            Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (editText!= null && getActivity() != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(
                                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                        editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: What is handler and where do I get it from?

Comment: @omega: I have added handler code. Just paste it in your code and replace editText with your name and try.